# Creating a new javascript object based on another object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a new javascript object that'll have new key names based on another object. I'm almost there, but my code fails at the line `// fails here` with `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined` . Any idea how to get this right? Also, is there a more efficient way to build a new object in this case? I need it work on older IE browsers, hence this approach.

```js
    originalObj = {"name":"John","age":30,"state":"CA","country":"USA"};
    
    objCodes = {"name":101,"age":102,"state":103,"country":104};
    
    // newObj = {101:"John", 102:30,103:"CA",104:"USA"};
        
    newObj = {};
    
    for (var i in originalObj) {
      if (objCodes.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
          // console.log(i, originalObj[i]);
          console.log(objCodes[i],originalObj[i])
          newObj.objCodes[i] = originalObj[i] // fails here
          
        
       }
    }
    
    console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: `newObj[objCodes[i]] = originalObj[i]`

Answer (score 1):

Just change the line like in the snippet below

```js
originalObj = {"name":"John","age":30,"state":"CA","country":"USA"};
    
    objCodes = {"name":101,"age":102,"state":103,"country":104};
    
    // newObj = {101:"John", 102:30,103:"CA",104:"USA"};
        
    newObj = {};
    
    for (var i in originalObj) {
      if (objCodes.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
          // console.log(i, originalObj[i]);
          console.log(objCodes[i],originalObj[i])
          newObj[objCodes[i]] = originalObj[i] // fails here
          
        
       }
    }
    
    console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
originalObj = {"name":"John","age":30,"state":"CA","country":"USA"};

objCodes = {"name":101,"age":102,"state":103,"country":104};

// newObj = {101:"John", 102:30,103:"CA",104:"USA"};
    
newObj = {};

for (var i in originalObj) {
  if (objCodes.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      // console.log(i, originalObj[i]);
      console.log(objCodes[i],originalObj[i])
      newObj[objCodes[i]] = originalObj[i] // fails here
      
    
   }
}

console.log(newObj);
```

Change the dotted notation to bracket notation. <strike>Reason for this is JavaScript allows only valid names with dotted notation which cannot start with numeric value.And In your case the keys are set to be 101,102...and so on, which are invalid.</strike>

Edit : Dynamic property names can be used only through bracket notations, such as in your case where the property name is set using a variable.

Comment: Because the `newObj.objCodes[i]` will not work regardless of what the value of `objCodes[i]` is, numerical values has nothing to do with it. You need `newObj[objCodes[i]]` because `objCodes[i]` is a variable and the `newObj` key is being set dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the keys, iterate them and copy the items like this:

```
originalObj = {"name":"John","age":30,"state":"CA","country":"USA"};

objCodes = {"name":101,"age":102,"state":103,"country":104};

// newObj = {101:"John", 102:30,103:"CA",104:"USA"};
    
newObj = {};

Object.keys(objCodes).forEach(i => newObj[objCodes[i]] = originalObj[i]);
```